# Как сделать, чтобы программа запускалась сама?

Tags: python

Есть парсер для сайта. Как сделать, чтобы он автоматически запускался каждый день в конкретное время (или несколько раз) автоматически. 
P.S. Всё написано только на питоне.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте  запуск по cron. Данный пример приведен для Unix систем

> crontab -e

Внесите  строку

> 0-59 * * * * /home/user/script.py - Пример запуска каждую минуту

Comment: Не могли бы поподробнее? )

Comment: Парсер сайтов в основном по такому принципу работают, или это оригинальное решение?

Comment: Если каждую минуту запускать, то чем плох вариант `* * * * * command`? @Mistin, подробнее можно найти в гугле, в ответе приведен пример его использования.

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от используемой операционной системы - для unix cron (см мануал, общая суть в сообщении выше, утилита crontab, ключ -e для создания джоба, в строке периодичность запуска и путь до исполняемого файла), для windows - планировщик windows (job scheduler, в гуи уверен разберетесь)

Answer (score 1):

для windows 7

добавляем задание из питона

```
from os import system

system(r'schtasks /create /tn parser /tr D:\documents\scripts\parser.pyw /sc HOURLY /mo 3 /ru login /rp password')
# /tn - название задания
# /tr - путь к скрипту
# /sc HOURLY /mo 3 - выполнять каждые 3 часа
# /ru - логин учетной записи windows
# /rp - пароль
```